# Translating a negative mV signal to CMOS level

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, analog, cmos, gain

I'm currently thinking of a circuit that will need to translate the output of a SIPM into a CMOS signal. And I'm looking for some input and ideas.

The SIPM output signal has a rise time of approximately 0.5ns to 0.7ns. The SIPM outputs 0V when nothing is detected and -70mV when something is detected. The fall time of the SIPM is 4.5ns.
The SIPM output signal needs to be translated to a CMOS signal with 0V to 3.3V (no less than 2.9V, Vcc will be most likely 3.3V).
So the -70mV from the SIPM should translate to 2.9V (CMOS) and 0V to 0V. Additionally, the frequency of the SIPM output would be in the range of 67ns to 100ns (most likely in the 12MHz range). The min. pulse duration of the CMOS signal should be 10ns, but even 30ns should be fine.

Would it be possible to use a comparator, like the LTC6957 to translate the output of the SIPM into a CMOS signal?
Or are there any other sensible alternatives?

In a wider picture, there will be 8 SIPMs but the CMOS readout device will only have 4 channels.
Does it make sense to use a multiplexer before the CMOS signal output, so 4 SIPMs at a time can be read out? Or should the SIPM output signals already be multiplexed?

Thanks

Datasheet LTC6957:

- https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/6957fb.pdf

Comment: You need to know the pulse width in order to select a comparator.

Comment: Compare figure 8 to your signal and allow sufficient margin for the overdrive values.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no SIPM expert by any means, but it sounds like the SIPM outputs that you'd like to turn into CMOS act a lot like particle detector outputs.
So I would suggest you look to another family of LTC comparators: [LT1715](https://www.analog.com/en/products/lt1715.html)/[17190](https://www.analog.com/en/products/lt1719.html)/[1720](https://www.analog.com/en/products/lt1720.html)/[1721](https://www.analog.com/en/products/lt1721.html).

These comparators draw a lot less power than the LTC6957 and have an input common mode range that extends to 100mV below ground.  So you should be able to tie their inputs directly to your SIPM output signal, with a reference/threshold of (say) -50mV to the other input, and get your CMOS output signal.  The supply range is 2.7 to 5.5V, so they can accommodate any CMOS supply in that range.

While their propagation delay is 4-4.5nsec, they can respond to faster signals and should work for the SIPM signals you described.  There is a detailed discussion section titled Speed Limits in the LT1720/1721 datasheet, which makes it clear that the output stage is the primary source of delay.  Not surprisingly, Jim Williams used them to create a coincident (particle) detector that works down to 3nsec ([Figure 15 on AN75 p10](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/an75f.pdf)) using the two comparators in an LT1720.  So, think of 4.5nsec as the Latency, more than the response time of these puppies.  My mental model of this is that once the internal hysteresis is thrown, the output will respond...when the output stage can get around to driving the load given the parasitics of the package, etc.

As for your need for a 10nsec min CMOS output pulse, these comparators can help with that too. Take a look at the rightmost part of Figure 12 in the [LT1720/21 Datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/17201fc.pdf) "Optional Logarithmic Pulse Stretcher (see text)". The text asserts that the pulse stretcher output "will be proportional to the logarithm of the input pulse width."  While that may not be particularly important for your case, it should be a source of ideas on how to assure the pulse width is always at least the 10nsec you need.

I should mention that the Tpd is specified with 20mV of overdrive, and they are faster than that for larger overdrive signals.  So if you could tolerate the noise of adjusting your threshold/reference to (say) -35mV, things get slightly faster.  Likewise they are specified with 10pF of output load, and the "Propagation Delay vs Load Capacitance" chart on p5 of the LT1720/21 datasheet indicates Tpd <3.5nsec with very light loads. And the discussion of the Pulse Stretcher text previously mentioned talks about 2ns and even just 1ns needed at the comparator inputs.

The LT1719 is a single comparator, and the LT1715 is a dual comparator, both of which have separate negative supplies for the input stage (down to -5.5V), should -100mV of input range be insufficient.  The outputs are still CMOS compatible based on the Power Supply vs Ground. The LT1719 also has a shutdown control if you need that.

PS The [LTMag/LTJournal](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/single-supply-dual-comparator-optimized-for-3v5v-operation.html) article that came out when these products were introduced, indicates that the same designer did them as the LTC6957. {For the latter, this statement is based on the inventor of the patents cited on the front page of that [Datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/6957fb.pdf).}